# How to run an actions on collection of sprites?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I try to run some actions on array of sprites, and need to run this actions in sequence for the sprites, the problem is when I use for loop its apply the action at once and there is not a period of time between them.

```
func setColors() {
    for color in boyColors {
        color.run(.wait(forDuration: 0.3))
        color.run(.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5))
    }
}
```

When call this function its should fade in the colors
of boyColors array with some time period between them, but its fade in all the colors ate once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all 4 to fade in concurrently after a delay:

```
func setColors() {
   let seq = [SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.3),SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5)]
    for color in boyColors {

        color.run(SKAction.sequence(seq))
    }
}
```

If you need them to fade in sequentially:

```
func setColors() {
    var seq = [SKAction]()
    let wait3 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.3)
    let wait5 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5)

    for color in boyColors {
        let colorFadeIn = SKAction.run({color?.run(fadeIn)})
        let group = [wait5,colorFadeIn]
        seq.append(wait3)
        seq.append(SKAction.group(group))
    }
    scene.run(SKAction.sequence(seq))
}
```

What this does is allow your scene (or any node you want to fire the actions) to control when a fade event starts.  This assumes that all nodes are running at the same speed.  If you need the nodes to run at individual speeds, you are going to need something a lot more complex like SomaMen proposes that chains your next colors action to the end of your current color.  You will have to also check if color exists in this regards, because if you do a chain like RGBY, and you remove G, the only color that will fire is R.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of SKActions available to you, including a run with completion, which you could use. One possible approach could be -

```
var colors = boyColors // so we can remove each item as we've faded it in
var waitAndFadeIn: (() -> ())?

waitAndFadeIn = {
    guard let boyColor = colors.first else { return } // stops when we run out of items

    let wait: SKAction = .wait(forDuration: 0.3)
    let fadeIn: SKAction = .fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5)

    let sequence: SKAction = .sequence([wait, fadeIn])

    boyColor.run(sequence, completion: {
        colors.remove(at: 0)
        waitAndFadeIn?() // do it again with the next boyColor 
    })
}

waitAndFadeIn?()
```

This would fade in the objects, one after the other. I think the code will run, but it's back-of-the-envelope sort of stuff which I haven't been able to test.

Comment: Chain all actions into 1 sequence instead of using completion.  There is a bug with the completion handler that it could fire twice depending on what you do with a node (like moving to a new parent)